# Using SubString when not knowing position or length

Tags: sql

Can anyone help me as I need to extract the number after `"Reference=" in the enclosed?` It's not possible to know the number of characters before or after the number as well as the length of the number (could also be letters and numbers) but it will always be

`After "Reference="
Before ",Description"`

`Object=CTSENORaanG,Reference=0000021357,Description=Test,Currency=EUR,Initial_Date=15Aug2011....`

The string is from a table with a huge amount of rows and I need to insert reference of each row into another table

Comment: which DBMS you're using and the number is always ending with `,`?

Answer (score 2):

SQL Server

```
declare @str varchar(1000)
set @str='Object=CTSENORaanG,Reference=0000021357,Description=Test,Currency=EUR,Initial_Date=15Aug2011....';

select substring(col,1,charindex(',',col)-1) from
(
select substring(@str,charindex('Reference=',@str)+10,100) as col
) as t;
```

MySQL

```
set @str:='Object=CTSENORaanG,Reference=0000021357,Description=Test,Currency=EUR,Initial_Date=15Aug2011....';

select substring(col,1,locate(',',col)-1) from
(
select substring(@str,locate('Reference=',@str)+10,100) as col
) as t;
```

Answer (score 1):

If the delimiter is constantly a comma `,`, then you can split the string. Then, you can split it further if the delimited sub-string is also consistent with `=`. Once you fish out `Reference`, you'll get it's equivalent value.

```
/* your test string */
string s = "Object=CTSENORaanG,Reference=0000021357,Description=Test,Currency=EUR,Initial_Date=15Aug2011";     
string[] arr = s.Split(',');

/* will contain the value you're looking for */    
string target = String.Empty;

foreach (string item in arr)
{
   string[] entry = item.Split('=');
   if (entry.Length == 2 && entry[0] == "Reference")
   {
      target = entry[1];
      break;
   }
}
```

Comment: BTW the syntax here is C#. As you did not specify which language you're using, you should nevertheless get the idea.

Comment: Sorry it's sql server and I run into problems because I need to have "set @str= (Select Column from MyTable where Column like '%xx%'". I probably didn't describe well enough - what I need is to split a huge amount of rows from one column into huge amount of rows into multiple columns e.g.

Comment: Object=CTSENORaanG,Reference=0000021357,Description=Test,Currency=EUR,Initial_Date=15Aug2011....

Reference  Description  Currency  Etc.

Comment: 0000021357  Test  EUR
0000021365  Test1 DKK

so can't just have set as a single row

Comment: Each object have the same content and reference='xxx' always ends with , as it the rest of the numbers/text

Answer (score 0):

```
use
pos = explode(",",string);
foreach(pos as po)
{
    p = explode("=",po)
    i=0;
    foreach(p as a)
    {
        if(a[i]== Reference)
        {
            echo p[i+1];
            i++;
        }
    }
}
```